# Updating table using string mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, web-services

I have this string response coming from the server :

```
string '{"code":1,"status":200,"data":
[{"connect_id":"3","equipment_id":"1","sample_id":"33","test_id":"44","message_type":"test_ordered","sent_date":"0000-00-00"},
{"connect_id":"12","equipment_id":"34","sample_id":"234","test_id":"234","message_type":"asdasd","sent_date":null}]}'
```

I have to update my local table's fields using the values found in `"data"`.
In case a value coming from the response is `NULL` (on a particular field from "data"),  there should be no changes to that field when updating the local table.

The table to be updated has many fields but let's say I want to update only the following three fields: `equipment_id,sample_id,test_id`.

After the update is succesfull I have to send back a response to the server telling that the transaction was succesfull and to update it's `status` (which is a field of the table's server from where the data has been collected to send the response) so the server won't send the response twice.

Comment: and where did you get stuck? You can use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: got stuck on the part where i have to process my variable $response that already holds the string i posted above and process it and update values in the local table's fields, a foreach should do it i think but some help would be appreciated

Comment: As I said, use json_decode(). This gives you a nice object to work with.

Comment: I agree but I got some errors, maybe you can help me with the loop and query, considering $response=json_decode('string i posted above'); ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show your code and the errors you get. You should edit your question to include code and errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using PDO and a valid pdo-connection in variable $dbc. I assume further that you identify your rows via the connect_id. You should change this according your needs.

Following code should give you an outline how to tackle this. Please regard my comments. I doesn't have done all for you, especially omitted the error handling.

```
$result = json_decode($response, true);
// You should validate that the decoding was successful and
// that the result contains all the data you expect.

// You find your data as in $result['data']
// This is an (numbered) array of associative arrays with your "columns" as key
// and the data as value

// prepare your update statement
$q = $dbc->prepare('
    UPDATE mytable 
    SET 
        equipment_id = ?, 
        sample_id = ?, 
        test_id = ?
    WHERE
        connect_id = ?
    ');
foreach ($result['data'] as $row) {
    // and execute it while looping through the data-array with
    // the appropriate data. Please note that the order of the
    // parameters got to be the same as in the prepared statement
    $params = array(
        $row['equipment_id'], 
        $row['sample_id'], 
        $row['test_id'],
        $row['connect_id']
    );
    $q->execute($params);
    // check success of the execute too.
}
```

Comment: Got it to work eventually, thank you for your help sir, here have a cookie :)